# How to configure a Facebook Application for sub domains

Tags: facebook, configuration, facebook-authentication

I'm building a Multi-Tenant application and I'm **struggling** incorporating a Facebook Login into the web application.

The tenants are using a sub-domain for example

```
http://tenant-1.domain.com/
http://tenant-2.domain.com/
http://tenant-3.domain.com/
```

So, I have created an application and when it comes to add the Website, how can I make it to be available in all tenants? Something like:

[image]

But of course, that does not work, and if I add just `http://domain.com/` it does not work either on `http://tenant-1.domain.com/` as soon I click in the `<fb:button-login>` I get:

[image]

> **How do I do this**, without creating a specific FB App for each tenant?

I'm using this to help persons to subscribe their account, I just want the login to get **name and email**, or they need to fell that up in the name and email boxes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, but there are options to workaround. I think probably the best would be to use a single domain to perform the authentication, specified as the redirect_uri. On this redirect_uri you can append some query parameters, for example your redirect_uri could be:

`http://auth.domain.com/auth.php?tenant=tenant-1`

Then in the code for auth.php you would grab this tenant parameter from the query string, authenticate the user, store their access token and then immediately redirect them back to `tenant-1.domain.com`

I'm not sure if this solution will be something you prefer, but it is currently not possible to specify subdomains for authentication, so this or a similar workaround is necessary.

Comment: not exactly what I would like to have :( will try something else.

Comment: Actually, this does seem to work if you include the http:// with the app domain. Check out this answer for more information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932191/facebook-app-on-subdomains-site-url-vs-app-domains It does mean that you will have to have a different subdomain for each app though!