# Authenticating an App for Multiple Domains

Tags: facebook, oauth

I've built a tiny FB app whose purpose is to get the user's public profile URL. I have used the [client-side authentication example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) provided, and it works just fine. I have also setup an application on Facebook.com so I can provide an APP ID. For this use, I have left App Domains blank, and made the app the type "Website with Facebook Login". And then I supply the "Site URL", the callback.

[image]

My trouble is that my web application runs across multiple domains. Individual customers have their own unique subdomain on our main domain. Do I have to create a new application for every single subdomain? It appears that way now, which would lead to hundreds — possibly thousands — of applications just to get a working callback URL for every customer domain.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I gave up and moved on with my life. :-(

Comment: Ah, your case is a bit different from mine- looks like in your case, it should work for you by editing settings because facebook supports sub-domains for the same domain name (a.xyz.com, b.xyz.com etc.)

Comment: Have a look at this related question/answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361941/how-to-configure-a-facebook-application-for-sub-domains

Comment: We can't use js sdk in this case. You will have to use server side apps as documented by Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)

Comment: a serverside authentication would allow the facebook app to sign in from different domain?

Answer (score 0):

> For this use, I have left App Domains blank

You might want to reconsider that; especially you might want to *read* the explanation text for “App Domain” parameter that hovering over the `[?]` shows …

Comment: I did read it, but anything I entered had no effect on the outcome. Can you please explain further for my benefit and anyone else coming after?